# Using a for loop to calculate the mean of a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, mean

My assignment is to use a for loop to acquire the means of the integers, which are vaccination rates per county, assigned to the second index of the tuples in the list below. I've looked through similar Q/A's and tried to adapt provided solutions, but I can't seem to relate them to my tuple list in a way that works.

```
vacc_counties = [
    ("Pulaski", 42.7),
    ("Benton", 41.4),
    ("Fulton", 22.1),
    ("Miller", 9.6),
    ("Mississippi", 29.4),
    ("Scott County", 28.1),
]
```

I get the mean is the sum of the second index divided by the length, sum()/len(), but I can't figure out how to refer to that second index, or how to associate a variable with the instances of the numbers in the second index across the whole list. I'm lost on finding the proper syntax here to acquire sum and length, and to divide them in a way that outputs the mean.

Some Q/A's mention importing pandas or numpy.mean, but I'm stuck figuring out out how to apply them to my own code.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vacc_counties = [
    ("Pulaski", 42.7),
    ("Benton", 41.4),
    ("Fulton", 22.1),
    ("Miller", 9.6),
    ("Mississippi", 29.4),
    ("Scott County", 28.1),
]


#To get a tuple in the list, in this case the first tuple:
print(vacc_counties[0])

#To get a value in the tuple, in this case the second value in the second tuple:
print(vacc_counties[1][1])



#Apply this to a loop:
for tup in vacc_counties:

    #For every tuple in the list it prints the second value of the tuple
    print(tup[1])


#To get the means:
#Get all percents into list
percents = []
for tup in vacc_counties:
    percents.append(tup[1])

#Now add up all the percents to get a total
total = 0
for percent in percents:
    total += percent
#Finally divide the added percents by the length of percents
print(total/len(percents))
```

If you have anymore questions, drop them here!

Comment: Thanks for the walk through and break down, this was just what I needed. Your answer has solved the problems and given me a leg up on the stuff that's been giving me trouble. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 possible solutions:

Using `sum()` + `len()`

```
vacc_counties = [
    ("Pulaski", 42.7),
    ("Benton", 41.4),
    ("Fulton", 22.1),
    ("Miller", 9.6),
    ("Mississippi", 29.4),
    ("Scott County", 28.1),
]
avg=round(sum(x[1] for x in vacc_counties)/len(vacc_counties),2)
print(avg)
```

Using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(vacc_counties)
print(array[:,1].astype(float).mean())
```

Comment: Thank you! These solutions work. I appreciate your sharing them. I've learned new things. Thank you again.

Comment: Most welcome @Psiberian_Mushky Consider acceting and upvoting the answer if it solves the question

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about using pandas or numpy until you have the basics of Python down. Those are libraries that offer a more compact and faster way for data scientists to manipulate data.

As you're looping over the data

```
for county_data in vacc_counties:
```

You can get the first item in the tuple with `city = county_data[0]`, and the second item with `vaccination_rate = county_data[1]`

So together that is

```
for county_data in vacc_counties:
    vaccination_rate = county_data[1]
```

I'll leave it to you to then figure out the exact code for getting the mean, but basically you'll want to follow the following three steps:

1. Before you begin the loop you'll need to create a variable for keeping track of the running total
2. Then inside the loop you'll want to add each vaccination rate to that running total.
3. After the loop when it comes time to divide the running total by the total number of items, use the [len function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the total number of items in your `vacc_counties` list. (The total number of tuples will be the same thing as the total number of vaccination rates).

---

Alternatively, you did mention the [sum function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) in your question. You would think that finding the average would be one place that the sum function would come in handly, and it can. If you wanted to use the sum function you would need a separate list that only has numbers in it. What theRealJake did when creating his `percents` list. Once you have created that list you could then easily call the `sum` function on your list to get the total. e.g. `total = sum(list_of_numbers)`.

Comment: This is more than great! Huge thanks for the breakdown and conceptual walk-through. I'm going to work with this to figure it out. That answers the problems plaguing me most about addressing the second index and referring to them. Thanks again!