# Using a for loop to calculate the mean of a list of tuples in Python with map and zip

Tags: list, dictionary, tuples, zip

I was reading the answers about question in thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538651/using-a-for-loop-to-calculate-the-mean-of-a-list-of-tuples-in-python](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Although the answers have helped me, I need to question how to finish what I was unsuccessfully trying.

My code is:

`` `vacc_counties = [ ``
`("Pulaski", 42.7),`
`("Benton", 41.4),`
`("Fulton", 22.1),`
`("Miller", 9.6),`
`("Mississippi", 29.4),`
`("Scott County", 28.1),`
`]`

`data = map(list, zip(*vacc_counties))`

`for i in data:`

`print(i)``

I have obtained these 2 lists:

`['Pulaski', 'Benton', 'Fulton', 'Miller', 'Mississippi', 'Scott County']`

`[42.7, 41.4, 22.1, 9.6, 29.4, 28.1]`

But now my problem is that I don't know how to store them in 2 variables, in order to calculate the mean after that.

I have tried something like this, among lot of other things:

`i0=[]`

`i1=[]`

`for i in data:`

`if i==0:`

`i0.append(i)`

`else:`

`i1.append(i)`

`print(i0)`

`print(i1)`

But the result is strange -the first blank list, plus a list into other list[[..]], and for the second element of the tuples a list with the 2 lists inside, so I think I don't know what I'm  doing:

`[]`

`[['Pulaski', 'Benton', 'Fulton', 'Miller', 'Mississippi', 'Scott County']]`

`[]`

`[['Pulaski', 'Benton', 'Fulton', 'Miller', 'Mississippi', 'Scott County'], [42.7, 41.4, 22.1, 9.6, 29.4, 28.1]]`

If somebody could finish this code to obtain the mean, and explain me why I have obtained this strange result, I would appreciate it because I'm really lost.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the below solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the results from map function direct to variables and use it for further calculations.

Try the below solution:

```
vacc_counties = [ ("Pulaski", 42.7), ("Benton", 41.4), ("Fulton", 22.1), ("Miller", 9.6), ("Mississippi", 29.4), ("Scott County", 28.1), ]

data = list(map(list, zip(*vacc_counties)))
cntryNames,cntryValues = data

print(cntryNames)
print(cntryValues)
```

Now after this you can apply your calculations on this list.